# previous row oracle in cursor

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, cursor

I'm here because i could not finde anywhere else if there is a way to return the previous value in a loop (Cursor) to compare with the current value, for instance..

> Cursor.Value = Cursor-1.Value;

It's bacause i have several contract numbers that i need to send by mail to the Business sector, but, in order to resume all the rows i want to compare if the current contract number are the same as the last contract number and validate it to dont send duplicated contract numbers.

Exemple of Record that i to skip in order to send no duplicate "Order Numbers":                    (Order_Number is my Key, not a sequencial numeric id):

> cCursor.Value = cCursor-1.Value
>
> cCursor.(111) = cCursor-1.(111)

Exemple of Record that i want to save in order to send as a processed "Order Number":                    (Order_Number is my Key, not a sequencial numeric id):

> cCursor.Value = cCursor-1.Value
>
> cCursor.(132) = cCursor-1.(111)

My Regards.

Comment: What is your code and cursor? Why aren't you just selecting the DISTINCT records?

Comment: I'm not sure that your edit clarifies anything.  I'm guessing at what your pseudocode is intended to mean but it still appears that you are talking about wanting to use the `lag` function.  But you've said that this isn't what you're interested in so I'm a bit confused. Perhaps it would be clearer if you posted actual code, sample data, expected output, etc.

Comment: It's because all the process happen into a for `FOR cisiOrder IN cGetCISINewOrders LOOP` 
this is my cursor `cGetCISINewOrders` is from here that i take all my `order_numbers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant reference backwards. Th easiest alternative is to store the key value (contract_id) in a variable and have logic like:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 IS .....;
   vLastContractID  NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
      IF vLastContractID != r1.CONTRACT_ID THEN
         -- do something
         vLastContractID := r1.CONTRACT_ID;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Well, i've been trying to do this with backwards info from a cursor, since we cant haha, i will follow your tip, thx @TenG for your help

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking.

A cursor is a forward-only structure.  You cannot fetch a prior row, just the next row (or set of rows).  Your query, however, can certainly include data from prior rows using the `lag` function.  For example, this will show you the `ename` for the prior row in your result

```
SELECT empno, ename, lag(ename) over (order by empno) prior_ename
  FROM emp
 ORDER BY empno
```

In a PL/SQL loop, you can also obviously have a local variable that has the data from the previous row that was fetched and use that to compare against the data from the most current row.

Comment: Well, that's not what i was seeking for, but may i could figure it out somehow, thx anyway

Comment: @YuriAguirre - If that's not what you are asking, please feel free to edit your question to clarify what it is that you are asking.

Comment: I've edited my question, may it could be easier to you now to figure it out, sorry for my bad explanation

Answer (score 0):

Please use ANALYTICAL function to check for prior or post rows. LEAD,LAG functions are best way to do this.